# Find the last index from the array using ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the traditional ngFor for iterating across an array followed with index, my sample code:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of Objects; let i = index">
```

I want to know is it possible to get the last index from the array in i? I know I can find the first or any other by if i === 1, etc, but is there a method to check directly if i is the last one from the array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div *ngFor="let object of Objects; let i = index; first as isFirst; last as isLast">
```

`isFirst` and `isLast` will be booleans.

But then again, [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) explains it !

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let object of Objects; let i = index; first as isFirst; last as isLast"> 
<div *ngIf="first">{{object}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i! While this may answer OP's question, code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. It is more beneficial for OP and future visitors to add an explanation to code provided. Thanks! --From Review

Answer (score 0):

I think its already in there, you can use

```
{{Objects.length-1}}
```

to get the last index of your array